# Как блокировать клавиатуру в C#

Tags: c#

Создал программу которая выдает тесты для ученика а вот теперь нужно чтобы только мышка действовала а клавиатура не работала т.е её нужно заблокировать чтобы ученик не смог выходить или сворачивать программу.Чтобы любое нажатие клавиша игнорировалась.

Comment: Вы хотите заблокировать в частности Ctrl-Alt-Del + запуск Task Manager'а? Это надо делать на системном уровне. Погуглите Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

Погуглите KeyPressed.  Она обрабатывает нажатие клавиш. это событие, кажется. Я б там блокировал.